# Loop through registry and get all subkeys and the values in RegistryKey in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, registry

I need to loop through the registry and get all subkeys and the all values.

This it's what I been trying (to get all subkeys only):

```
public void OutputRegKey(RegistryKey Key)
{
    foreach (string keyname in Key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey key2 = Key.OpenSubKey(keyname))
            {
                foreach (string valuename in Key.GetValueNames())
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(valuename);
                    OutputRegKey(key2);
                }
            }
         }
         catch
         {

         }
    }
}
```

How do I get all the values? I need to do two methods: one that gets all the subkeys and other that gets all the values. I'm only asking the one to get all the values. Thank you.

PS: It's not homework or otherwise related to academics. It's something personal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once given the `RegistryKey`, you could easily get the key's `ValueNames` by `Key.GetValueNames()` and to get each of the individual key's `Value` for each `ValueName` by `Key.GetValue(valueName)` which will `return` an `object`.

Borrowing your code to elaborate, here is how it should be modified to,

```
private void processValueNames(RegistryKey Key) { //function to process the valueNames for a given key
    string[] valuenames = Key.GetValueNames();
    if (valuenames == null || valuenames.Length <= 0) //has no values
        return;
    foreach (string valuename in valuenames) {
        object obj = Key.GetValue(valuename);
        if (obj != null)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(Key.Name + " " + valuename + " " + obj.ToString()); //assuming the output to be in comboBox1 in string type
    }
}

public void OutputRegKey(RegistryKey Key) {
    try {
        string[] subkeynames = Key.GetSubKeyNames(); //means deeper folder
        if (subkeynames == null || subkeynames.Length <= 0) { //has no more subkey, process
            processValueNames(Key);
            return;
        }
        foreach (string keyname in subkeynames) { //has subkeys, go deeper
            using (RegistryKey key2 = Key.OpenSubKey(keyname))
                OutputRegKey(key2);
        }
        processValueNames(Key); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //error, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, but the code has an error: In "OutputRegKey" the "catch (Exception e)" must catch the "using (RegistryKey... ". Otherwise the "foreach (..." is exited and the recursion is incomplete!

Comment: @marsh-wiggle I think also has a one problem, for example, when I try to get all value under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" it returns empty, do u have any idea for this?